# Combining 2 different, nested filters with Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

so i am playing around with the js-isotope library. works great so far, but have an issue on a specific task.

i have a grid which represents brands for clothing. the brands are organized by the starting letter.

so it looks like this: http://towa-online.at/sagmeister/marken/

i created 2 isotope-objects:

1. alphabet-grid: grid-items containing the list of brands

```js
var $container_alphabet = $( '.sagmeister-brand-grid' ).isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    gutter: 40,
    columnWidth: 320
  },
  filter          : '*',
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 750,
    easing  : 'linear',
    queue   : false
  }
});
```

2. brand-grid: each list inside an alphabet

```js
var $container_brands = $( 'ul.brand-by-letter' ).isotope({
  itemSelector    : '.brand-name',
  layoutMode      : 'vertical',
  filter          : function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    var result_query = search_query ? $this.text().match( search_query ) : true;
    var result_cat   = search_cat ? $this.is( search_cat ) : true;
    return result_query && result_cat;
  },
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 750,
    easing  : 'linear',
    queue   : false
  }
});
```

what i wanna do is, after filtering the brands ( that works fine ), i am checking on the "arrangeComplete"-event, if maybe some letters are emtpy. if so, i add a class "no-items" to the grid-item from the alphabet-grid and at the end i am triggering isotope for that.

```js
$container_brands.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ){
  var $grid_item = $( '#' + event.currentTarget.id ).parent();
  var has_items  = ( filteredItems.length > 0 );

  if ( has_items ){
    $grid_item.removeClass( 'no-items' ).addClass( 'has-items' );          
  } else {
    $grid_item.removeClass( 'has-items' ).addClass( 'no-items' );
  }
  if ( $grid_item.is( ':last-child' ) )
    $container_alphabet.isotope();
});
```

it seems that the triggering doesn't work every time, but just from time to time.

anyone thought on this one?

Answer (score 0):

so, i was able to find a solution myself. thanks anyway, it helped me to describe the problem and have an another look at it :)

my solution was to alter the structure a little bit and then I put in a custom filter-function for the grid-items for the alphabet, which is checking if all children are filtered out or not. if so, hide the alphabet-item :)

nice start for the week, like that ^^

cheers

PS: if you need a more detailed explanation, feel free to ask. would be glad to help!